# Using Camel 2.1 with Grails 1.2.1 - Classloading problem

Tags: spring, grails, apache-camel

I'm trying to define a Camel context in my Grails application.

**resource.groovy:**

```
xmlns camel: 'http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring'
camel {
    camelContext(id:'camelContext') {
    }
}
```

Results in a stacktrace containing:

> 2010-02-03 13:24:42,209 [main] ERROR spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator  - [RuntimeConfiguration] Unable to load beans from resources.groovy
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/spi/ManagementStrategy

The strange thing is that ManagementStrategy is in lib/camel-core-2.1.0.jar. I'm not that familiar with neither Spring nor Camel so any suggestions are welcome. Can this be a classloader issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the release notes for Apache Camel 2.1
http://camel.apache.org/camel-210-release.html

There is a section with new .jar dependencies. 
You need commons-management .jar on the classpath.